# Is there a way to bind an array to mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I'm trying to make a class that will execute any one of a number of stored procedures with any amount of variables

Im using php and mysqli

- My class enumerates an array and constructs a string based on the number of elements if any
- giving something like this `CALL spTestLogin(?,?)` for example
- I now need to bind the input from my array using somethin like this:

  $stmt->bind_param($this->paramTypes,$this->paramValues);//paramValues is my array

Then if that works I can work on getting my results

Any ideas

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something like this:

```
$params=array_merge(
    array($this->paramTypes), 
    $this->paramValues
);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

given that `$this->paramTypes` is a string in the format required by `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` - if not, you have to create this `string` parameter first.

I don't know if `out` or `inout` parameters do work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` will take a variable number of arguments

Assuming `$this->paramTypes` is also an array holding the correct type character for each variable (one of 'i', 'd', 's', 'b'), you could do something like

```
$params = $this->paramValues;
array_unshift($params, implode($this->paramTypes));
call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_param' ), $params);
```

Essentially you create an array of the parameters you would normally pass to bind_param(),  and then  make the call using `call_user_func_array()`

There may be a much better way of doing this

**Edit**: just realised I was beaten to it while writing this, I'll leave this answer here for now in case it is of interest