# PHP Variable within bind-parameter

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following PHP variable:

```
$qStr1;
```

This, when printed or echoed, shows the following:

```
$q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5
```

I have a bind-parm code:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);
```

This works fine and saves correctly to the database, however, when I replace the individual parts with the variable (see below), it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $qStr1);
```

Vardump is as follows:

```
string(49) "$q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10"
```

Comment: can you post the out of var_dump($qStr1); ?

Comment: so $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4 etc. are not actual variables are they ?

Comment: It's a `string` isn't it?  How would I turn that into variables?  I'm clearly having a moment....

Comment: you might intend it to be a string but when you add a $ sign in front of it, there are bound to be cases when PHP might treat them as variables while you want them to be treated as strings. That is not a good practice.

Comment: See amended code above.

Comment: are $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5 actual variables where you plan to store some other values ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - I need them as variables.

Comment: then you might want to store $qStr1 as array of variables and make corresponding changes to your bind function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280798/is-there-a-way-to-bind-an-array-to-mysqli-prepare

Comment: Thanks Maximus2012 will look at now but that is getting beyond my ability!!!  I'm going to have to invest more time in learning.

Comment: `iss$is`  could you explain this bit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. The method wants several parameters. No you give it one, which holds a string.

There are possibilities to do this, like `eval`, but I advise you to look for a different approach. PDO for example can bind using names which can be called in a loop.

Comment: Yes, I've gathered as much - this is getting beyond my experience and was hoping for some guidance.

Comment: The quick and dirty way would be to use `eval`, the "good" way is really to go back a few steps and see if you really need what you think you need.

Comment: It might help if you could explain why you want to do it like this. I can't see anything wrong in adding those 10 variables to the bind function call, but maybe you have your reasons for this.

Comment: I need to be able to programatically do this as I have upwards of 10 pages with circa 10 to 50 questions on each - without it done like this I have manually code each page.

Comment: As above - the reason is that I could have upwards of 50 questions on a page and didn't want to have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the manual

***The number of variables and length of string types must match the parameters in the statement.***

That function expects x parameters to match the number of statement parameters and has not been written to expand one parameter into many.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to work out - how to expand $qStr1 into the variables I need.

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought you were just trying to pass the one param and expecting the mysqli call to do the expansion

Answer (score 0):

$qStr1 is a string which contains the names of the variables, not the content of the variables. It just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

From the `var_dump`, you can see that `$qStr1` is just a string with all the variable names (not values) inside it.

If you're using single quotes for defining the variables, this will happen. So, if you want `$qStr1` to have the actual variables' value, then you'll have to enclose it in double quotes:

**Example:**

```
<?php

$q1 = '1'; 
$q2 = '1';
$q3 = '1';
$q4 = '1';
$q5 = '1';

$qStr1 = '$q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5';
var_dump($qStr1);

$qStr1 = "$q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5";
var_dump($qStr1);
```

**Output:**

```
string(23) "$q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5"
string(13) "1, 1, 1, 1, 1"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this is it - $q1, $q2 etc. are the variables I need.  They are currently stored in a string but I need it to look like this for the purposes of saving to the db. `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);`

Comment: Appreciate the update but no - this isn't what I am looking for.  I am trying to find a way to `loop` or something `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);` so I don't have to manually code thr $q1, $q2 etc.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is what you need: `echo "mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, \"iss$is\", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $qStr1)";`

Comment: That is indeed what I have but it doesn't work as $qStr1 needs to be replaced by its actual contents to make the bind-param work.